# Make a toggle "switch" in batch file

Tags: batch-file, toggle, hide, show

I want to toggle a directory with the attribute `-h` & `+h` accordingly.

When I use this command sequence the output is

```
\directory was unexpected at the time.
```

Any ideas on how to get this working?

```
:toggle
if attrib \directory /s /d equ -h goto hidedir
if attrib \directory /s /d equ +h goto showdir
pause
goto start

:showdir
attrib -r -s -h \directory /s /d
goto start

:hidedir
attrib +r +s +h \directory /s /d
goto start
```

Comment: You can't use `IF` with the `attrib` command, you need a `FOR ... LOOP` like here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658509/how-to-get-attributes-of-a-file-using-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little batch code to toggle hidden attribute of a specified directory using the technique as explained on question [How to get attributes of a file using batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658509/)

```
@echo off
set "Directory=C:\Temp\Test Directory"
for %%D in ("%Directory%") do set "Attributes=%%~aD"
if "%Attributes:~3,1%"=="h" goto UnhideDir

%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe +h "%Directory%"
goto :EOF

:UnhideDir
%SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -h "%Directory%"
```

The information required to understand `FOR` loop and `%%~aD` is output by entering in a command prompt window `for /?` or `help for`.

And running `set /?` or `help set` in a command prompt window and reading the help printed helps to understand the substring comparison in `IF` condition which compares just fourth character in string with the attributes of the directory. (First character is referenced with index value 0.)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure folder to process
    set "folder=.\test"

    rem Determine the needed attribute
    set "newMode=+h"
    for %%f in ("%folder%") do for /f "tokens=2 delims=h" %%a in ("%%~af") do set "newMode=-h"

    rem Change the attribute to new mode for the indicated folder and its contents
    "%systemRoot%\system32\attrib.exe" %newMode% "%folder%" 
    "%systemRoot%\system32\attrib.exe" %newMode% "%folder%\*" /s /d
```

In this code a `for` is used to obtain a reference to the folder and a `for /f` to determine the presence of the `h` attrib in the list of folder attributes. The variable `%newMode%` will get the required `attrib` command parameter to adjust the attributes of the folder an its contents

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
attrib \directory /d | findstr "^....H" && set "switch=-" || set "switch=+"
attrib %switch%r %switch%s %switch%h \directory /s /d
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this might help just change the links to what ever command you want

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (work.txt) do (
  set NUM=%%a
)

if %NUM%==1 goto start
echo incorrect
goto close

:start 
start "Youtube playlist" "https://www.youtube.com"
echo 2 > work.txt 
exit

:close 
start "imager" "https://imgur.com/"
echo 1 > work.txt
exit
```